# Calculate proportions of multiple columns

Tags: r, function, group-by, lapply

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
location = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
               times = c(4, 6, 3, 7))
ID = (1:20)
Var1 = rep(c(0,2,1,1,0), times = 4)
Var2 = rep(c(2,1,1,0,2), times = 4)
Var3 = rep(c(1,1,0,2,0), times = 4)

df=as.data.frame(cbind(location, ID, Var1, Var2, Var3))
```

There are different locations where we evaluated variables with three levels each (score 0, 1, 2). Now I would like to get a result that contains the proportions of each score by location. The number of individuals examined (ID) is not the same at each location.

So what I did was making functions to use with lapply:

```
score0 = function(a){sum(a==0)}
score1 = function(a){sum(a==1)}
score2 = function(a){sum(a==2)}
```

And I tried this, as well as  many other things:

```
df %>%
  group_by(location) %>% 
  lapply(FUN = score0)
```

But it doesn't work. Again, what I would like to get is a data frame with the proportions of each score or level (0, 1, 2) per location. Or at least the number of occurrences of each score, so I can divide it by the number of individuals per location.
I hope this makes sense.
I also checked this question [Calculate proportions of categories within groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71185490/calculate-proportions-of-categories-within-groups) but cannot apply the solution to my data with multiple variables.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you show how you want your result table to look?  do you want a separate summary column for each of Var1, Var2, Var3 or a single column combing them?

Comment: Please see my answer below @George Savva.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Var"), values_to = "score") %>%
  type_convert() %>%
  group_by(location) %>%
  count(score) %>%
  mutate(frac = n / sum(n))
```

resulting in

```
# A tibble: 12 × 4
# Groups:   location [4]
   location score     n  frac
   <chr>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
 1 A            0     3 0.25 
 2 A            1     6 0.5  
 3 A            2     3 0.25 
 4 B            0     7 0.389
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @danloo, this was almost it. What I wanted was this:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Var"), values_to = "score") %>%
  type_convert() %>%
  group_by(location, name) %>%
  count(score) %>%
  mutate(frac = n / sum(n))
```

with the following result:

```
# A tibble: 36 × 5
# Groups:   location, name [12]
   location name  score     n  frac
   <chr>    <chr> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
 1 A        Var1      0     2   0.4
 2 A        Var1      1     2   0.4
 3 A        Var1      2     1   0.2
 4 A        Var2      0     1   0.2
 5 A        Var2      1     2   0.4
 6 A        Var2      2     2   0.4
 7 A        Var3      0     2   0.4
 8 A        Var3      1     2   0.4
 9 A        Var3      2     1   0.2
10 B        Var1      0     2   0.4
```